# When to include foo.h in foo.cpp

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, header-files

I have frequently seen people `#include "foo.h"` at the top of "foo.cpp". It looks like you *could* always do this, but people don't. So there must be some reason behind the choice.

When should I `#include` the header (foo.h) inside the source file (foo.cpp)?

Comment: Could you provide an example where you don't include (and it compiles properly)?

Comment: @UnholySheep As far as I can tell, this is actually done pretty rarely. For instance, look at any major C++ project on GitHub.  e.g. TensorFlow is Google's biggest open source project and they don't do this very often at all in the source code: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow

Comment: If `foo.h` defines a class and `foo.cpp` defines the class's member functions, then `foo.cpp` must include `foo.h`. In other cases it's mostly optional, but I can't think of any reason not to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the time to look through that source code in detail. I just picked 3 random C++ files from the core/kernel folder and all of them included their corresponding headers.

Comment: @Brian So you think people don't do this if the foo.h/foo.cpp file doesn't define a class, just stand-alone functions? That's interesting.

Comment: I think that's the case where you can *get away* with not including `foo.h` in `foo.cpp`, but I still don't see why. Plus, anyone who writes C will be in the habit of including `foo.h` in `foo.c` even though there are no classes, since it guards against messing up the declaration and definition so that they don't match. (That doesn't work in C++ because you're allowed to overload functions, but the habit carries over.)

Comment: As for TensorFlow, you should keep in mind that it follows the company style guide, in which including the header in the `.cc` file is mandatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason to put it at the top is simply to check that its contents don't depend on any other headers. For example:

```
// foo.h
void f(std::vector<int>& v);

// foo.cpp
#include <vector>
#include "foo.h"

// foo1.cpp
#include "foo.h"
#include <vector>
```

In foo.cpp, there's no problem: everything compiles just fine. foo1.cpp, on the other hand, won't compile, because foo.h uses `std::vector` without an include directive.

Having every header file compilable on its own avoids mysterious failures that otherwise occur when you change include directives in a file that has nothing to do with foo.cpp. These are sometimes hard to identify, and they're always frustrating.

Comment: So, by this logic, I should always include "foo.h" in "foo.cpp". Is that your suggestion?

Comment: @theJollySin -- yes. Every file that defines anything that's declared in foo.h should `#include` foo.h. It's cheap insurance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the header if you're using anything inside the header.

For example, if you need to create `foo someObject = new foo();` in your main method, you need to include the header `foo.h`that has that class definition.

You only need to include things that you know you're going to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can include a header file whenever you want.
Anyway, suppose you have a file `main.h` similar to the following one:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H
struct S { };
#endif
```

Now, this `main.cpp` works just fine, as you mentioned:

```
void f() { }
#include "foo.h"
int main() { f(); }
```

Anyway, if I slightly change the `main.cpp` it doesn't work anymore:

```
void f() { S s{}; }
#include "foo.h"
int main() { f(); }
```

The problem is that `S` is declared after its first use and it is not visible when the definition of `f` is encountered for the first time.
So, the rule of thumb could be - *include a header immediately before you start using something (let me say) imported by that file*.

Anyway, this could quickly lead to messy files with `#include` directives spread all around and a common practice is to simply put all of them at the top of the file and that's all.